# shared_ptr not returned correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MarchingEvent
{
public:
    MarchingEvent() {}
};

class DerivedEvent : public MarchingEvent
{
public:
    DerivedEvent() {}
};

std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> function1()
{
    return std::make_shared<DerivedEvent>();
}

std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> function2()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> event = function1();
    if (event)
        return event; // This line crashes...

    return std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent>();
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> event = function2();

    std::cout << "hello";

    return 0;
}
```

When running **function2()** I get a crash at line **return event;**, the crash is a SIGABRT and I can trace back to std file **shared_ptr_base.h** in the context of:

```
  // Counted ptr with no deleter or allocator support
  template<typename _Ptr, _Lock_policy _Lp>
    class _Sp_counted_ptr final : public _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>
    {
    public:
      explicit
      _Sp_counted_ptr(_Ptr __p)
      : _M_ptr(__p) { }

      virtual void
      _M_dispose() noexcept
      { delete _M_ptr; }
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Make the dtors for DerivedEvent public and MarchingEvent virtual and see if that helps.

Comment: Maybe you corrupted the heap in your previous code and the crash happens later (which is normal for heap corruption).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @cplusplusrat there is no need for a virtual destructor when assigning to a shared_ptr from make_shared. The deleter is type-erased.

Comment: @cplusplusrat: this does not help

Comment: @drescherjm: what would be a case of heap corruption?

Comment: @arennuit 1) Your [mcve] does not compile, due to few typos. If I fix it: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please confirm, that you can reproduce the issue, with the example, that you show. 2) "_what would be a case of heap corruption?_" Could be anything involving undefined behavior.

Comment: ***what would be a case of heap corruption?*** There are many causes. Not following the rule of 3/5/0 is one. On windows using a dll compiled with an incompatible CRT is another ( only VS2015 and 2017 are compatible - all other versions of Visual Studio are incompatible with each other). Also corruption may happen from accessing out of bounds of a heap variable. There are also double deletes and freeing memory with a modified pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple MCVE. It will prove that either:

a) your implementation has a bug (extremely unlikely), or

b) you have a bug or UB somewhere else (extremely likely)

example MCVE:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MarchingEvent
{
};

class DerivedEvent : public MarchingEvent
{
};

std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> function1()
{
    return std::make_shared<DerivedEvent>();
}

std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> function2()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent> event = function1();
    if (event)
        return event; // This line crashes...

    return std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent>();
}



int main()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MarchingEvent>> v(10000);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 10000 ; ++j)
        {
            v[j] = function2();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

strong evidence for my claim: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b554b334212a0ea